# Process multiple directories and all files within using snakemake

Tags: python, linux, snakemake

I've got a directory with 10 sub-directories (dir01 to dir10) and a number of files in each of those (new files are added every day to the sub-directories).

I'm trying to write a `snakemake` file that will go through all of the sub-directories and all the files and process them (run my `convert.exe` executable to convert my .Stp files to .Xml). The processed files will be moved to a new directory but into sub-directories with the same names as before and the same file name.

So - as an example in the end the final job flow should run similar to this:

```
/data01/dir01/Sample1.Stp --> processed by convert.exe --> /data01/temp/dir01/Sample1.xml
```

I'd also like to divide this over the 12 CPUs I've got access to, running it in parallel.

I've just started using snakemake and have gone through a couple tutorials however am getting a little lost.

Here is what I have so far:
It's not working and I'm not even sure if this is the write way to go about it.
This is also only the first part - just trying to loop through the directories and files (not trying to convert or run in parallel yet).

```
directories = glob_wildcards("/data01/{dir}")
files = glob_wildcards("/data01/{dir}/{file}")

rule all:
        input:
                expand("/data01/temp/{dir}/{file}.moved.Stp", dir=directories, file=files)

rule sort:
        input:
                "/data01/{dir}/{file}.Stp"
        output:
                "/data01/temp/{dir}/{file}.moved.Stp"
        shell:
                "..."
```

Any help about how to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Based on this [FAQ entry](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-do-i-run-my-rule-on-all-files-of-a-certain-directory), try this:

```
directories, files = glob_wildcards("data01/{dir}/{file}")

rule all:
    input:
        expand("data01/temp/{dir}/{file}.moved.Stp",
               zip, dir=directories, file=files)

rule copy:
    input:
        "data01/{dir}/{file}.Stp"
    output:
        "data01/temp/{dir}/{file}.moved.Stp"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

Your `glob_wildcards` are not working. You would need

```
directories, = glob_wildcards("/data01/{dir}")
```

But you really need to glob everything in one go, as in my example. `expand` will make all (N x N) combinations of the two input lists. You could use that feature if you have exactly the same files in every directory. However, providing `zip` combines the two lists element by element.